# How to create a list from splitting a list elements in python?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have:

```
sentences = ['The girls are gorgeous', 'I'm mexican']
```

And I want to obtain:

```
words = ['The','girls','are','gorgeous', 'I'm', 'mexican']
```

I tried:

```
words = [w.split(' ') for w in sentences]
```

but got not expected result.

Will this work for Counter(words) as I need to obtain the frequency?

Comment: `'I'm mexican'` is invalid syntax. use `"I'm mexican"` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method didn't work because, `split` returns a list. So, your code creates a nested list. You need to flatten it to use it with `Counter`. You can flatten it in so many ways.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
Counter(chain.from_iterable(words))
```

would have been the best way to flatten the nested list and find the frequency. But you can use  a generator expression, like this

```
sentences = ['The girls are gorgeous', "I'm mexican"]
from collections import Counter
print Counter(item for items in sentences for item in items.split())
# Counter({'mexican': 1, 'girls': 1, 'are': 1, 'gorgeous': 1, "I'm": 1, 'The':1})
```

This takes each sentence, splits that to get the list of words, iterates those words and flattens the nested structure.

If you want to find top 10 words, then you can use [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method, like this

```
Counter(item for items in sentences for item in items.split()).most_common(10)
```

Comment: What if I want to get the 10 most repeated right away?

Comment: @diegoaguilar You can use [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method like this `print Counter(item for items in sentences for item in items.split()).most_common(10)`

Comment: Nice @thefourtheye You should edit your question so it helps more people in future .. Thanks again deeply

Comment: @diegoaguilar You meant the *answer*, right? ;) I updated it :)

Comment: God yeah, answer. I'm soo tired now and get confused

Answer (score 6):

Try like this

```
sentences = ["The girls are gorgeous", "I'm mexican"]
words = [word for sentence in sentences for word in sentence.split(' ')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
words = ' '.join(sentences).split()
```